# Getting expired_client_token on Authorize Code Grant Access Token

Tags: postman, docusignapi

I am falling over on the first hurdle of working with DocuSign APIs and need some help.

I have the DocuSign Rest API collection imported into Postman. I have the iKey, iSec, encodedKeys and codeFromUrl variables set.

When trying to send the '01 - Authorize Code Grant Access Token' post API I am getting the below response every time.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "expired_client_token"
}
```

I have tried removing everything from Postman, including the environment, and removing the app from DocuSign, and starting fresh so that all of my keys are new, but I still get the same error.

I am new to working with APIs so it is possible that I have missed something really obvious.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step you need to do is to obtain user consent as described over [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/)

After granting consent you will be redirected to the redirect url you provided in the Auth URL mentioned in the link above and along with it there will be a parameter called "code" that you need to use in the Authorization Code Grant token request inside the "code" parameter within ~90 seconds, after those 90 seconds you will get the "expired_client_token" error

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! The bit I was doing wrong is using the Authorization Code Grant Token after 90 seconds. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me as well. I just did a reset on the variables and then run Authorize token POST api.